# select from database and use js for get variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem with my code. I want to execute the following script:

1. Select a man.
2. Select date.
3. Select time, but considerate (hide) hours in which a man is busy. I need to do a varible with hours when men is busy and use it in jquery.datepicker.

My code:

```php
Select man:
<?php
    include ("dbconfig.php");
    $conn->select_db("zapis");
    echo '<form action="ShowSelectedValue.php" method="POST">';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo '<select  name="ad1" class="form-control" id="ad1" >';
        echo '<option value="0">0. Dowolny stylista</option>';
        $zapytanie = $conn->query("SELECT id, imie, nazwisko FROM sytlisci_m");
        while($row = $zapytanie->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'"> '.$row['id'].' '.$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
$zapytanie->free();
$conn->close();
?>
Select date and time:
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" data-date="2013-02-21T15:25:00Z">
  Date:
    <input size="10" type="text" name="date" class="date" />
  Time:
    <input size="10" type="text" class="time" />
</div>
<script>
    $('#ad1').change(function(){
        var Destination=$('#ad1').val();
        $.ajax({url:"ShowSelectedValue.php?Destination="+Destination,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".ShowSelectedValueDiv").html(result);
        }});
    });
    $('.form_datetime .date').change(function(){
  var datka=$('.form_datetime .date').val();
  $.ajax({url:"ShowSelectedValue.php?datka="+datka,cache:false,success:function(result){
    $(".ShowSelectedValueDiv1").html(result);
  }});
});
</script>

<div class='ShowSelectedValueDiv'>
<?php
    include ("ShowSelectedValue.php");
?>
</div>
<div class='ShowSelectedValueDiv1'>

</div>
```

And ShowSelectedValue.php

```php
<?php
include ("dbconfig.php");
$a=$_GET['Destination'];
$conn->select_db("zapis");
$stylista = $conn->query("SELECT imie FROM sytlisci_m WHERE id='$a'");
while($abc = $stylista->fetch_assoc()){
$d = $abc['imie'];
}
try{
  $js_ddates = "";
    $q=$_GET['datka'];
  $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT data, godzina FROM klient_zapisany WHERE stylista_k = '$d' AND data='$q'");
  while($record = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    $godz = $record['godzina'];
    $hour = strtotime(''.$godz.'');
    $js_ddates .= "['".$godz ."'".", "."'".date("H:i", strtotime("+30 minutes", $hour)) ."'"."],";
      }

  echo $js_ddates;
}
catch(\PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "</div>";

$stmt->free();
$conn->close();
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(".form_datetime .time").timepicker({
     'minTime': '7:30',
     'maxTime': '22:00',
     'timeFormat': 'H:i',
     'step': 30,
     'disableTimeRanges': [<?php echo $js_ddates; ?>]
   });
   $('.form_datetime .date').datepicker({
     'format': 'yyyy-m-d',
     'autoclose': true
   });

</script>
```

When I choose man and date, i see that all hours are enabled (I add to database events). Where is a problem?
I think, that when I choose date, varible with a man is forgotten, but i don't know how to repair it.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Why do you have the `jQuery` in the php file you are querying? The point of using `ajax` is to post/get while keeping the client on the page, if you want/need to use `jQuery` on the results then it should be done in the `success:` function. Also the `jQuery` in your query page `ShowSelectedValue.php` will do nothing but return a syntax error since it doesn't have the `jQuery` library loaded. **Edit:** Also you might want to use `JSON` rather than multiple `echo`'s to return data.

Comment: @NewToJs, I load jquery library in my script (i copied only fragment of my code). I have not errors on page. I can see results when i select a man and date, but $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT data, godzina FROM klient_zapisany WHERE stylista_k = '$d' AND data='$q'"); this query does not return correct result.